# Unable to load React class component inside other class component

Tags: reactjs, routes, components, react-router

i am new to react, i am trying to execute below code, but i am unable to load one class component into other  class component, below are my js file, please tell me what is wrong in my code

can anyone help for react Basic tutorials and react example

**Apicall.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { fetchjson } from '../helpers/helpers';
import posts from "../components/posts";
export default class Apicall extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { items: [] };
}
 componentDidMount() {

fetchjson('posts').then((data) => {
  this.setState({items: data});
});

}

 render() {
return (
  <div>
  <h1>API Call</h1>
  {this.state.items.map(item => 
  <div key={item.id}>
  <h4>{item.title}</h4>
  <p>{item.body}</p>
  <posts posttitle={item}/>
  </div>
  )} 
  </div>
);
}
}
```

**posts.js**

```
import React from "react";
export default class posts extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
 }
render() {
 return (
   <div>{this.props.posttitle.title}</div>
 );
}
}
```

Below is the output i am getting, unable to load the render from posts component
[image]

Comment: what is the error or behaviour that you get ?

Comment: Did you try to perform your `.map()` before the return ?

Comment: @panther above is behaviour which i am getting now, i am not able to load the content from posts component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined React components [must begin with an Uppercase character](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Change

```
import posts from "../components/posts";
```

to

```
import Posts from "../components/posts";
```

and

```
<posts posttitle={item}/>
```

to

```
<Posts posttitle={item}/>
```

You may also want to change the class name itself (`class posts ...` to `class Posts ...`, but it's not required when using `export default` (the importer declares the actual identifier that is used.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.